# How to specify the 5 apex items on my javascript code at oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, if-statement, oracle-apex, apex

[Please see picture on the link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLF8M.png)
How do I code 5 apex page items in a javascript using if else condition. Initially, what I am doing is i am trying to hide regions which will have empty page items and that depends on the sql query results. please help. thank you.

Here is my code:

```
if (apex.item("P82_SOLN_4" ).isEmpty()) {

$x_Hide("soln4");

} else {

$x_Show("soln4");

}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Does that code not work ? You could do this with dynamic actions as well, then there is no javascript needed.

Comment: @Koen Lostrie, my question is how do I code 5 apex items using this javascript function?

Comment: And also how do I do this using dynamic actions? Please help thank you

Comment: Please provide some more information. Do you want (1) to hide this regions permanently when the page loads or (2) hide/show them when a user changes a value ?

Comment: I want to hide the regions if the page item inside that region is empty. The content of the page item will be depending on the query results from the database.

Comment: My page items are P82_SOLN_1, P82_SOLN_2,  P82_SOLN_3,  P82_SOLN_4,  P82_SOLN_5. My regions corresponding to each items are soln1, soln2, soln3, soln4 and soln5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work it out now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To hide a region, put in a server side condition of ITEM IS NOT NULL on each of the regions.
For example, to hide region soln4, add server side condition of ITEM NOT NULL with ITEM P82_SOLN_4

Comment: it did not work. When I put ITEM IS NOT NULL on each region, everything was hidden. i dont want to hide all region, i will only hide region that which page item is empty (it will be based on my database)